# How to access a Docker HTTP server remotely?

Tags: apache-httpd, docker, proxy

I have an docker which exposes a caddy webserver on ports 8080 and 8443 mapped to 80 and 443 respectively.

I can access it with a local browser using https://localhost:8443, however, the browser will first complain that the SSL certificate is self signed.
For unknown reasons, when attempting to access using http://localhost:8080, the browser redirects https://localhost (https but without the port).

```
[michael@localhost api-platform]$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                    PORTS                                                                                                                               NAMES
b4f9c942d02f   api-platform_caddy   "caddy run --config …"   22 minutes ago   Up 22 minutes             2019/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp, :::8080->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8443->443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8443->443/udp, :::8443->443/tcp, :::8443->443/udp   api-platform_caddy_1
120471adcb43   api-platform_php     "docker-entrypoint p…"   22 minutes ago   Up 22 minutes (healthy)   9000/tcp                                                                                                                            api-platform_php_1
4ab23f9bd5d9   postgres:13-alpine   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   22 minutes ago   Up 22 minutes             0.0.0.0:5433->5432/tcp, :::5433->5432/tcp                                                                                           api-platform_database_1
958944520bd5   api-platform_pwa     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   22 minutes ago   Up 22 minutes             3000/tcp                                                                                                                            api-platform_pwa_1
[michael@localhost api-platform]$
```

I wish to access the docker's webserver from a another machine.  I have attempted the following, however, if there is a better way than my attempt to using the host's Apache webserver, I am fully open to changing the approach.

I have tried two versions (see below for both virtualhost config files).  Similar to when using without having Apache involved, http://api-platform.example.com:80 redirects to https.

**Pass the request to http://127.0.0.1:8080**.  Same behavior on either the local machine using https://localhost or a remote machine using https://api-platform.example.com/ and the browser displays "Client sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server". Docker logs are silent and Apache does not log errors, however, Apache's logs access:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Sep/2021:10:18:32 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 48 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0" (localhost)
11.22.33.44 - - [05/Sep/2021:10:34:18 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 48 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.63 Safari/537.36" (remote)
```

**Pass the request https://127.0.0.1:8443**.  For localhost, works as desired except browser complains first about self signed signatures, but for remote access, the browser displays `The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server` and Apache's access and error logs are displayed below.

```
11.22.33.44 - - [05/Sep/2021:10:29:10 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 341 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.63 Safari/537.36"
11.22.33.44 - - [05/Sep/2021:10:29:10 -0700] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 - "https://api-platform.example.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.63 Safari/537.36"
11.22.33.44 - - [05/Sep/2021:10:29:10 -0700] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 502 341 "https://api-platform.example.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.63 Safari/537.36"


[Sun Sep 05 10:29:30.461504 2021] [proxy_http:error] [pid 111778:tid 140510476093184] (103)Software caused connection abort: [client 11.22.33.44:53690] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server 127.0.0.1:8443
[Sun Sep 05 10:29:30.461535 2021] [proxy:error] [pid 111778:tid 140510476093184] [client 11.22.33.44:53690] AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by /
[Sun Sep 05 10:29:30.481675 2021] [proxy_http:error] [pid 111778:tid 140510240954112] (103)Software caused connection abort: [client 11.22.33.44:53690] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server 127.0.0.1:8443, referer: https://api-platform.example.com/
[Sun Sep 05 10:29:30.483998 2021] [proxy_http:error] [pid 111778:tid 140510257739520] (103)Software caused connection abort: [client 11.22.33.44:59869] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server 127.0.0.1:8443, referer: https://api-platform.example.com/
[Sun Sep 05 10:29:30.484012 2021] [proxy:error] [pid 111778:tid 140510257739520] [client 11.22.33.44:59869] AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by /favicon.ico, referer: https://api-platform.example.com/
```

Firewall settings are shown at the bottom of this post. How should one allow an HTTP server to be accessed remotely.

Virtual Host Config Files:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName api-platform.example.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/api-platform.example.com-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/api-platform.example.com-access.log combined
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/testing.example.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/testing.example.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>


<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName api-platform.example.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests off
    SSLProxyEngine On
    SSLProxyVerify none
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
    ProxyPass / https://127.0.0.1:8443/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://127.0.0.1:8443/
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/api-platform.example.com-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/api-platform.example.com-access.log combined
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/testing.example.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/testing.example.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

## firewall settings

```
[michael@localhost api-platform]$ sudo firewall-cmd --list-all
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: enp0s31f6 wlp0s20f3
  sources:
  services: cockpit dhcpv6-client ssh
  ports: 80/tcp 443/tcp 8080/tcp 8443/tcp
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
[michael@localhost api-platform]$
```

Comment: I just edited to make the fire-wall settings a section. Look how I used 3-single-back-quotes, on a line of their own at start and end of code, and a heading. I also upvoted. Hope someone can help.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor  Appreciate.  I finally got things somewhat working but don't know why and then they stopped working.  I am trying to get more info why.  Apache's logs just state error reading status which is not much to go on.  Possible to make Apache give more?  docker logs gives nothing.  I then tried to access caddy's logs inside the docker but /var/log is empty.  Any thoughts?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a web-server on the host. I suspect that it may be the file-wall on the host. It maybe blocking the ports.

Comment: Don't think a firewall issue (added `firewall-cmd --list-all` to original post and I am getting httpd log).  Also, agree I don't need a web-server on the host but it is already there and wanted to keep it with 80/443 and thus needed to change the docks published ports.  When not https, I understand why I get the `Client sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server` error, but I don't understand the proxy error and think I just messed up its virtual host file (does it look okay?).  Thanks